# comparison between pointer and integer, how can I fix it?? It does not even run

Tags: c

**I've got this code:**

```
char level;

printf("Please choose a level!\nEasy\nMedium\nHard\n\n");
scanf("%s", &level);
do{
    if((level=="easy") || (level=="Easy"))
    {
        printf("You have choosen the easy level, so you have 2 powerups per time. If you want to use them, please type P or p!\n");
        break;
    }
```

**and this warning:**
17  15  C:\Users\katerina\Desktop\levels.c  [Warning] comparison between pointer and integer

**What can I do?**

Comment: This is a quite rudimentary mistake, especially when coming from other languages. Consider taking a decent C tutorial or course.

Comment: Pro tip: see [this excellent list of recommended books on C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/562303/253056) and pick one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot compare string in C using `==`. Use `strcmp`:

```
if (strcmp ("easy", level) == 0)
```

Also, if you want your code to be safer, use `strncmp` as Bart mentioned.

---

Another thing you have to notice, is that declaring `level` like

```
char level
```

makes only space for one character to fit. ("easy" won't fit). I think you want to declare a string:

```
char level [length];
```

Just replace 'length' by the length of the string you want.

Comment: Thanks Ashish!! I appreciate a lot :)

Comment: @AshishAhujaツ: please don't beg for up-votes or answer acceptance - it's undignified, especially as your answer is is essentially the same as the first two answers.

Comment: @PaulR, I'm not begging. I never do this, unless I see a new user saying that it worked. They do not know the process of acceptation on SO, and thus I am just informing them. I wrote: accept my answer **if** it solved everything. Pay attention to the if. Also, before the user said it worked, I never even asked it do like accpetion of the answer.

Comment: @PaulR, also please define your wording of 'begging'. As per me, begging will be to ask a user to accept the answer, without any reason, whether it worked or not: _please accept my answer, I have put enough effort in it. It doesn't matter whether it works for you or not, it works for me_ or something like that. This is a correct answer, and it isn't wrong for asking for acception of the answer, if the user is coming and saying _it worked. thank you_. Also, if you see carefully, I was basically just informing the user of acception, and saying to accept the answer if it works.

Comment: @PaulR, it's common sense that if my answer hadn't worked, the user wouldn't have accepted it, and accepted the answer that worked.

Answer (score 2):

In C, there is no string comparison operator `==`. You have to use the [`strncmp`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ansi_c/c_strncmp.htm) function:

```
if (strncmp("easy", level, 4) == 0) {
}
```

Also, your variable `level` is incorrectly defined. It should be a `char *` (don't forget to allocate memory) or `char[]`.

Answer (score 2):

Two problems: firstly `level` needs to be a string, not a `char`. Secondly you need to use `strcmp` to compare strings, not `==`.

Comment: Thanks Paul, I fixed it!! :)